# Is inline validation convenient on pre filled form fields?

Tags: forms, validation, conversion, fields

I have a form which partly pre-fills after filling in an address field. Is it convenient to give green check marks on the fields they didn't fill in themself?

Comment: Yes. This is to inform the user that the content in those fields are validated and approved and give them the confidence to submit the form. Since you are using inline validation, it make sense to use the green check mark on all validated fields for consistency regardless if its auto filled.

Comment: Is there any testing data about this? Also it might be confusing for the user when you have a situation like this: Departement: not prefilled, first name: prefilled, last name: prefilled, gender: not prefilled, date of birth: prefilled, phone number: not prefilled, e-mail: prefilled. As you can see it might get confusing because of some fields aren't prefilled but the user sees a lot of green check marks.

Comment: If the fields are meant to be empty then don't add a check mark next to it. I thought you were talking about fields with autofilling features, e.g zip code look up table.

Comment: It's a business lookup function. So if you fill in an address we get the company name back but also the contact person. That information contains values like first name, last name, gender, phone number but not department and email for example.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, if the pre-filled data is user-editable

If the user can still edit the pre-filled fields, they need to know that the current data is valid and also if any changes they make, are.

Make sure all pre-filled data is indeed valid. You don't want to pre-fill data that somehow fails your validation. Test this.

#### No, if the pre-filled data is not user-editable

If the user cannot change the pre-filled data, make it clear the fields are inactive and do not validate them.

The user doesn't need to know if they are valid because they didn't enter or alter any data. If the data is somehow invalid, the user can't do anything about it, so they shouldn't be bothered with a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may seem useful that inline validation for pre filled form fields is ok, it depends on the kind of field that you are addressing. If the address fields are not critical to further information from the user, then you can use the green validation. Else it might be better to let the user validate the information.

Comment: But then, how the user is supposed to valid a pre-filled field?